# Boost::GIL read images from memory

Tags: image, memory, boost-gil

I need to be able to load images (jpeg, png etc.) from the memory in Boost::Gil framework.
Is there a way to do that?

Thanky for your answers!

Comment: Seems the status of this may have changed with an extension: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039199/boostgil-how-to-save-image-as-jpeg-or-png-into-char

Comment: See also answer of the sister question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039199/boostgil-how-to-save-image-as-jpeg-or-png-into-char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The according to the documentation the [read/convert functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/gil/doc/html/group___i_o.html) only accept filenames as input, not general streams or pointers, so this seems to not be possible.

Grep on the header files seems to agree too:

```
/usr/include/boost/gil > grep -nri stream *
/usr/include/boost/gil >
```

and searches for `void *` or `char *` don't return any relevant results either.

Comment: I'd guess at least one of the backend libraries it (presumably) calls to do the IO is structured such that this a reasonable design decision. IIRC readpng_init() takes a FILE*, which you could do with fmemopen() but it is annoying to expose FILE* to modern C++ code.

Comment: You can always mkfifo()+fork() to work around limitations like this in 3rd party code if it really is critical.

Answer (score 1):

See a solution here:

http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/gil-io-new-review-Reading-images-from-in-memory-sources-td3073639.html

cheers