# Boost::GIL How to save image as JPEG or PNG into char*?

Tags: c++, boost, save, jpeg, boost-gil

So I see samples all around on saving into file. But I wonder if it is possible to save into char* or string instead of file - so to say keep it in memory?

Comment: So you mean a raw memory buffer, representing a JPEG or PNG encoded image?

Comment: @Christian Rau: a raw memory buffer, with  a JPEG or PNG encoded image in it

Comment: GIL has ways to make copies of images already in memory ( http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/gil/doc/html/giltutorial.html#InterfaceSec , difference between images and image views).  What do you expect to get out of making  different copy of in-memory stuff to a bag of bytes that's also in memory?

Comment: @Max Lybbert - You could, as an example, use it to generate PNG byte streams over HTTP for generating images on the fly without writing to disk.

Comment: @Max Lybbert: Generally I want to do what `msandiford` proposed=)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything to facilitate this in boost itself.  All I/O seems to be based on supplying filenames.

However, there seems to be an extension [here](http://code.google.com/p/gil-contributions/) called `io_new` that has streams based I/O.

See documentation [here](http://gil-contributions.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gil_2/libs/gil/io_new/doc/io.qbk) for an example (search for "Reading And Writing In-Memory Buffers").

Comment: I can confirm that this is not possible in the boost mainline release. I ended up pulling in ImageMagick but it was heavier than I expected. `io_new` or just straight `libpng` is a cleaner solution

Comment: Note that the author of `io_new` is in fact the maintainer of Boost.GIL, so the quality of the code is bound to be high (and he posted on the Boost ML last month requesting to merge `io_new` into mainline Boost; not sure how that's going).

Answer (score 1):

Boost.GIL v1.75: reading [this docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/gil/doc/html/io.html) at the section *"Reading And Writing In-Memory Buffers"* seems **boost::gil::write_view(...)** can also write into a memory buffer.
Please see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76438775/boost-gil-write-an-image-into-a-memory-buffer)